# How to debug php-fpm crash ? Getting random php-fpm crash.

Tags: php

I am getting random php-fpm crash on our server. 
PHP version PHP 5.3.14. 
I am not able to find from where I should start debugging to find out root of the cause ?
Only special things we are dong are:
I am using custom compiled sqlite3 extension. 
We are doing custom session handling.

```
#0  0x00007f45c5d5d8a5 in raise (sig=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
#1  0x00007f45c5d5f085 in abort () at abort.c:92
#2  0x00007f45c5d9afe7 in __libc_message (do_abort=2, fmt=0x7f45c5e827c0 "*** glibc detected *** %s: %s: 0x%s ***\n")
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/libc_fatal.c:198
#3  0x00007f45c5da0916 in malloc_printerr (action=3, str=0x7f45c5e82ab8 "free(): invalid next size (fast)", ptr=<value optimized out>)
    at malloc.c:6311
#4  0x00007f45c5da3443 in _int_free (av=0x7f45c60b9e80, p=0xdadb80, have_lock=0) at malloc.c:4811
#5  0x00000000005aba3f in _zval_dtor_func ()
#6  0x000000000059ffb9 in _zval_ptr_dtor ()
#7  0x00000000004ac917 in ?? ()
#8  0x00000000005faab8 in ?? ()
#9  0x00000000005d21f0 in execute ()
#10 0x00000000005a23fa in zend_call_function ()
#11 0x00000000004a39f0 in ?? ()
#12 0x00000000005faab8 in ?? ()
#13 0x00000000005d21f0 in execute ()
#14 0x00000000005abd4d in zend_execute_scripts ()
#15 0x0000000000558948 in php_execute_script ()
#16 0x000000000063e959 in ?? ()
#17 0x00007f45c5d49cdd in __libc_start_main (main=0x63d300, argc=3, ubp_av=0x7fff7329c8a8, init=<value optimized out>, fini=<value optimized out>, 
    rtld_fini=<value optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fff7329c898) at libc-start.c:226
#18 0x0000000000422069 in _start ()
```

Second

```
#0  0x000000000058efe8 in ?? ()
#1  0x00000000005a4452 in destroy_op_array ()
#2  0x00000000005b8cdb in zend_hash_destroy ()
#3  0x00000000005a451a in destroy_zend_class ()
#4  0x00000000005b89a5 in ?? ()
#5  0x00000000005b8aa9 in zend_hash_reverse_apply ()
#6  0x00000000005a040e in ?? ()
#7  0x00000000005acc82 in ?? ()
#8  0x00000000005593d5 in php_request_shutdown ()
#9  0x000000000063e02d in ?? ()
#10 0x00007f45c5d49cdd in __libc_start_main (main=0x63d300, argc=3, ubp_av=0x7fff7329c8a8, init=<value optimized out>, fini=<value optimized out>, 
    rtld_fini=<value optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fff7329c898) at libc-start.c:226
#11 0x0000000000422069 in _start ()
```

Third

```
#0  0x000000000058ef49 in ?? ()
#1  0x000000000058f0fb in ?? ()
#2  0x00000000004b163e in ?? ()
#3  0x00000000005ae1cc in ?? ()
#4  0x00000000005b8a94 in zend_hash_reverse_apply ()
#5  0x00000000005acbfd in ?? ()
#6  0x00000000005595b5 in php_request_shutdown ()
#7  0x000000000063e02d in ?? ()
#8  0x00007f45c5d49cdd in __libc_start_main (main=0x63d300, argc=3, ubp_av=0x7fff7329c8a8, init=<value optimized out>, fini=<value optimized out>, 
    rtld_fini=<value optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fff7329c898) at libc-start.c:226
#9  0x0000000000422069 in _start ()
```